# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController Get Image from Contact Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Can someone tell me please how I can get the Image fron the picked Person in Swift please ? I use ABPeoplePickerNavigationController..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ABPersonHasImageData(person ) {
    let profilePicture = UIImage(data: ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatOriginalSize).takeRetainedValue())!
    let profilePictureThumbnail = UIImage(data: ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail).takeRetainedValue())!
    println("\(profilePicture)")
    println("\(profilePictureThumbnail)")
}
```